# Image Rotate 3D in Flex, but display another image on back of this image?

Tags: apache-flex, 3d, rotation, effect

i want to rotate 3D an Image called img1 in Flex. I want to rotate it around y axis 180 degree. I can do this by using 3D effect already built in Flex but i want to do a bit more different.

I want during rotating, there's another image called img2 appear on back of img1 (in default case, the image appear on the back is img1) and when rotating finish, the image will be img2.

How can i do this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, now i found a solution. Please check it here, it's very easy to do.

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/921258

Answer (score 0):

If you need no perspective effect, it's quite easy to do. A rough implementation (not tested!):

```
// Event.ENTER_FRAME event listener
void on_enter_frame(event:Event):void
{
   // m_angle is a member of the class/flex component where on_enter_frame is declared
   // ANGLE_DELTA is just a constant
   m_angle += ANGLE_DELTA;
   // Angle clamping to the range [0, PI * 2)
   m_angle %= Math.PI * 2;
   if (m_angle < 0)
      m_angle += Math.PI * 2;

   // If we currently look at the front side...
   if (m_angle < Math.PI)
   {
      img1.visible = true;
      img2.visible = false;
      img1.scaleX = Math.cos(m_angle);
   }
   else
   {
      img1.visible = false;
      img2.visible = true;
      // If you omit negation, the back-side image will be mirrored
      img2.scaleX = -Math.cos(m_angle);
   } 
}
```

So every frame we increase the rotation angle, clamp it to the range [0, PI * 2). Then depending on the value of the rotation angle, we hide/show the pair of your images, and then perform x-scaling of the visible image.